# Why is my Eureka lemon tree losing leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, lemons

I have an Eureka lemon tree that was doing great over the winter. I repotted it with Miracle grow soil and it has slowly started to drop the leaves and it has a couple brownish colored limbs.

I again repotted it today with citrus potting soil to see if that helps. Can anyone tell by the pic what is going wrong with it and what I need to do to correct the issue? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No sign of scale or spider mites. No sign of nutrient deficiency either. Those are the most common problems

Comment: So you think it is fine?  Just possibly was in the wrong soil?

Comment: Did you accidentally let it go dry?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I have always watered all the plants at the same times and the rest are good.